# Adding Time out section in powershell script

Tags: powershell, timeout, powershell-2.0

I am trying to test Time out after 30 seconds.

Sample code:

```
$a = "y"
$b = "n"
$timeout = New-TimeSpan -Seconds 30
$stopwatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
$stopwatch.Start()
$timeout.Seconds
$stopwatch.elapsed.Seconds
do{

    if($a -eq "n"){
        Write-Host "This block will never run"
        break
    }

    if($stopwatch.elapsed.Seconds -lt $timeout.Seconds){
        Write-Host "Testing this block: Time OUT!!"
        break
    }

}while($a -eq $b)

$stopwatch.Stop()
```

But the if block if($stopwatch.elapsed.Seconds -lt $timeout.Seconds) is true even $stopwatch.elapsed.Seconds value is 0 and $timeout.Seconds value is 30 in the loop and complete the code in few milliseconds and not taking 30 seconds to print the Time out statement.

Could anyone please give me pointer to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sivam The issue is-

- You're not applying the proper properties of the timespan command if it goes beyond 59 seconds then at 60 seconds it will consider it 1 minute.
- Update the condition inside the loop if($stopwatch.elapsed.Seconds -lt $timeout.Seconds)

Try

```
$a = "y"
$b = "n"
$timeout = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 1
$stopwatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
$stopwatch.Start()
$timeout.Minutes
$stopwatch.elapsed.Minutes
do{
    if($a -eq "n"){
        Write-Host "This block will never run"
        break
    }
    if($stopwatch.elapsed.Minutes -ge $timeout.Minutes){
        Write-Host "Time OUT!!"
        break
    }
}while($a -ne $b)
$stopwatch.Stop()
```

Comment: Using `.Minutes` suffers the same conceptual flaw as using `.Seconds`: you're only checking the minute _component_ of the timespan, not the _total amount_ of minutes. While your command is less likely to malfunction, it still can, namely if the more than 1 _hour_ has elapsed before the `$stopwatch.elapsed.Minutes -ge $timeout.Minutes` test. For instance, `([timespan] '01:01').Minutes` is `1`, even though the timespan represents `61` seconds. /cc @shivam

Comment: Also, _will consider it 1 minute_ is a bit confusing, given that a `[timespan]` instance represents a duration that can be expressed in any unit, on demand - you're
free to ask for the duration of a 1-minute timespan in seconds (`.TotalSeconds`) or minutes (`.TotalMinutes`), for instance.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things:

- You don't need these two lines: `$timeout.Seconds` and `$stopwatch.elapsed.Seconds` above the loop
- Your while condition should be `while($a -ne $b)`
- The test inside the loop should read `if($stopwatch.elapsed.Seconds -ge $timeout.Seconds)`

Try

```
$a = "y"
$b = "n"
$timeout = New-TimeSpan -Seconds 30
$stopwatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::new()
$stopwatch.Start()
do {
    if($stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds -ge $timeout.Seconds){
        Write-Host "Testing this block: Time OUT!!"
        break
    }
    # no timeout, so proceed with what needs to be done here
    # . . .
} while($a -ne $b)  # loop forever unless you set $a equal to $b in the loop somewhere

$stopwatch.Stop()
```

Comment: Hi Theo, Thank you for above suggestion.
I am trying to run Write-Host "Testing this block: Time OUT!!" after 30 seconds.
could you please suggest the if condition using $stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds -ge $timeout.Seconds in it.

Comment: @shivam Well.. if you run this, that code block wil run as soon as the elapsed time of the stopwatch (in seconds) is greater or equel to the `$timeout` TimeSpan you have set to a certain number of seconds. In fact, you don't even need that `$timeout` variable and you can simply hardcode to `if($stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds -ge 30)`. When a new StopWatch is started, the initial `.Seconds` wil be 0 and will increase over time.

Comment: Yes @Theo agreed, however I will parametrized the timeout value so that I can use as per the need that is reason i am trying with above condition

Comment: Theo, I originally thought that `$stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds -ge $timeout.Seconds` is fine, because the timeout is less than 1 minute, but then I realized that `$stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds` can be a problem - at least hypothetically: If, before the test, more than 1 minute has passed, you need to use `$stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds` for the test to work as intended.

Answer (score 3):

[Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72086805/45375) addresses incidental *logic* problems with your approach and offers a solution that *probably* will work, but isn't fully robust: If the activity in your loop *exceeds 1 minute* before the timeout condition is tested, the test won't work as intended (even with the logic problems fixed).

You have two options:

- Use `.TotalSeconds` instead of `.Seconds`, for the reasons explained below.
- More simply, taking advantage of the fact that `[timespan]` instances are directly comparable (see below), you can use:

  ```sh
  if ($stopwatch.elapsed -gt $timeout) { # ...
  ```

---

As [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) points out, **`[timespan]` instances are *directly comparable***, due to implementing the .NET [`System.IComparable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IComparable) interface (as well as its generic counterpart); e.g.:

```sh
   # -> $true - a timespan representing a 61-second duration 
   #            is greater than one representing a 60-second (1-minute) duration.
   [timespan]::FromSeconds(61) -gt [timespan] '00:01:00'
```

Therefore, as shown in the top section, you can simply directly compare `$stopwatch.elapsed` and `$timeout` - both of which are `[timespan]` instances.

The **`.Seconds` property** of a [`[timespan]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.TimeSpan) instance is  **only the seconds *component***, potentially alongside *larger* units, such as minutes (`.Minutes`) and hours (`.Hours`)

You need the **`.TotalSeconds` property** to get the ***total* amount of seconds** (analogously, there are also `.TotalDays`, `.TotalHours`, and `.TotalMinutes` properties).

Also note that `.Seconds` is always a *whole number* (`[int]`), whereas `.TotalSeconds` can be a *fractional value* (`[double]`).

To illustrate the difference:

```sh
PS> [timespan] '00:01:05' | # 1 minute and 5 seconds 
      Select-Object Seconds, TotalSeconds

Seconds TotalSeconds
------- ------------
      5           65
```